# Can't use paginate on a query result

Tags: cakephp, orm, pagination, cakephp-3.0

According to the doc http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html, I'd like to paginate a result of a query like below:

```
$unlocked_sitesQuery = $this->Deviceconnections
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Agthemes.Sites',
        'Agthemes.Agpois',
        'Agthemes.Agthemelanguages'
    ])
    ->where(['request' => 'unlock'])
    ->groupBy('agtheme.site.id');

$unlocked_sites = $this->paginate($unlocked_sitesQuery);
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Call to undefined method `ArrayIterator::alias()` 
>   File /home/mywebsite/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php
>   Line: 154

What does it mean?

**EDIT**
It seems that @ndm is right but the doc says:

> By default the `paginate()` method will use the default model for a     controller. You can also pass the resulting query of a find method:

```
public function index() 
{
    $query = $this->Articles->find('popular')->where(['author_id' => 1]); 
    $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

So it should work on a result set. Or I didn't understand what the doc explains. Possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you are passing the wrong type of object. Pagination on result sets is not supported, only tables (either objects or names) and queries are.

`groupBy` is not a method of the query class, it's one of the magic methods that are causing the query to be executed, and forward the method call to the resulting result set. So you end up calling `Cake\ORM\ResultSet::groupBy()`, which returns another collection.

- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Working with Result Sets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets)**

So if you need such grouped results in pagination, then you have to solve this (at least partially) on SQL level, for example by fetching the results the other way around, ie fetch `Sites` and their associations, and filter by `Deviceconnections.request`, something like this (no guarantee that this will give you the desired result, but the example should give you a hint!):

```
$query = $Sites
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Agthemes.Deviceconnections',
        'Agthemes.Agpois',
        'Agthemes.Agthemelanguages'
    ])
    ->matching('Agthemes.Deviceconnections', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return $query
            ->where([
                'Deviceconnections.request' => 'unlock'
            ]);
    });
```

You'd of course have to adapt your view code accordingly.

Comment: it seems you are right anyway the doc seems to say that result sets is supported. See my EDIT.

Comment: @caBBAlainB Nope, the docs say that you can pass a query. A "_resulting query_" is not a "_result set_", that's two different things, two different classes (`\Cake\ORM\Query`, `\Cake\ORM\ResultSet`), the former is a query that is being returned as a result, the latter is the result returned when executing a query (which is what you are doing). **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets**, **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects**

Comment: @dewwwald He's mark the answer as accepted, there is no necessity to upvote as well. However I've upvoted as it was exactly the answer I was needing (along with the additional comment).